# Inject 1903 into WDS image?

Tags: dism, windows-10-v1903

I know that I can inject updates into a WDS image through DISM, I'm wondering whether I could actually inject build 1903 itself into a 1803 image so as to not have to re-capture?

Has anyone tried this, been successful doing it?

Thanks.

Comment: Could someone migrate this to serverfault for me please, I accidentally posted on the wrong website...